# Statistics.corr of very large RDD[Vector] in Spark Causes Generated Code Limits to Be Reached: How to Fix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame with an arbitrarily large number of rows created by doing something similar to:

```
// pivot data to wide format
val wide = df.groupBy("id").pivot("ip").sum("msgs")

// drop columns and fill in null values
val dfmat = wide.drop("id").na.fill(0)
val dimnames = dfmat.columns
```

I have no idea how many different `"ip"`'s there will be. I'm then trying to take each row of `dfmat` and create an `RDD[Vector]` object for use with the `org.apache.spark.mllib.Statistics.corr`. To do that I'm doing the below and running into errors:

```
// try a different mapping
val mat = dfmat.rdd.map(row => Vectors.parse(row.mkString("[",",","]")))

// create correlation matrix
val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(mat, "pearson")
```

This works find for small datasets (1 million or less records), but fails when operating on the full dataset. I also get really, really big log records with weird records like:

```
/* 125222 */     this.value_8326 = -1L;
/* 125223 */     this.isNull_8327 = true;
/* 125224 */     this.value_8327 = -1L;
/* 125225 */     this.isNull_8328 = true;
/* 125226 */     this.value_8328 = -1L;
/* 125227 */     this.isNull_8329 = true;
/* 125228 */     this.value_8329 = -1L;
/* 125229 */     this.isNull_8330 = true;
/* 125230 */     this.value_8330 = -1L;
/* 125231 */     this.isNull_8331 = true;
/* 125232 */     this.value_8331 = -1L;
/* 125233 */     this.isNull_8332 = true;
/* 125234 */     this.value_8332 = -1L;
/* 125235 */     this.isNull_8333 = true;
/* 125236 */     this.value_8333 = -1L;
/* 125237 */   }
/* 125238 */
/* 125239 */   public org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BaseMutableProjection target(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableRow row) {
/* 125240 */     mutableRow = row;
/* 125241 */     return this;
/* 125242 */   }
/* 125243 */
/* 125244 */   /* Provide immutable access to the last projected row. */
/* 125245 */   public InternalRow currentValue() {
/* 125246 */     return (InternalRow) mutableRow;
/* 125247 */   }
/* 125248 */
/* 125249 */   public java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object _i) {
/* 125250 */     InternalRow i = (InternalRow) _i;
/* 125251 */     apply16668_0(i);
/* 125252 */     apply16668_1(i);
/* 125253 */     apply16668_2(i);
/* 125254 */     apply16668_3(i);
/* 125255 */     apply16668_4(i);
/* 125256 */     apply16668_5(i);
/* 125257 */     apply16668_6(i);
/* 125258 */     apply16668_7(i); 
/* 125259 */     apply16668_8(i);
/* 125260 */     apply16668_9(i);
/* 125261 */     apply16668_10(i);
/* 125262 */     apply16668_11(i);
/* 125263 */     apply16668_12(i);
/* 125264 */     apply16668_13(i);
/* 125265 */     apply16668_14(i);
/* 125266 */     apply16668_15(i);
/* 125267 */     apply16668_16(i);
/* 125268 */     apply16668_17(i);
/* 125269 */     apply16668_18(i);
/* 125270 */     // copy all the results into MutableRow
/* 125271 */     apply16669_0(i); 
/* 125272 */     apply16669_1(i);
/* 125273 */     apply16669_2(i);
/* 125274 */     apply16669_3(i);
/* 125275 */     apply16669_4(i);
/* 125276 */     apply16669_5(i);
/* 125277 */     apply16669_6(i);
/* 125278 */     apply16669_7(i);
/* 125279 */     apply16669_8(i);
/* 125280 */     apply16669_9(i);
/* 125281 */     apply16669_10(i);
/* 125282 */     apply16669_11(i);
/* 125283 */     apply16669_12(i);
/* 125284 */     apply16669_13(i);
/* 125285 */     apply16669_14(i);
/* 125286 */     apply16669_15(i);
/* 125287 */     apply16669_16(i);
/* 125288 */     apply16669_17(i);
/* 125289 */     apply16669_18(i);
/* 125290 */     apply16669_19(i);
/* 125291 */     apply16669_20(i);
/* 125292 */     apply16669_21(i);
/* 125293 */     apply16669_22(i);
/* 125294 */     apply16669_23(i);
/* 125295 */     return mutableRow;
/* 125296 */   }
/* 125297 */ }
/* 125298 */
```

And finally:

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:572)
    at org.spark-project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.spark-project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Code of method "(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass;[Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression;)V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificMutableProjection" grows beyond 64 KB
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.makeSpace(CodeContext.java:941)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.write(CodeContext.java:854)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.writeShort(CodeContext.java:959)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.writeConstantFieldrefInfo(UnitCompiler.java:10279)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.putfield(UnitCompiler.java:9956)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet2(UnitCompiler.java:5086)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$11800(UnitCompiler.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$15.visitFieldAccess(UnitCompiler.java:5062)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$FieldAccess.accept(Java.java:3235)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet(UnitCompiler.java:5070)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet2(UnitCompiler.java:5095)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$11900(UnitCompiler.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$15.visitFieldAccessExpression(UnitCompiler.java:5063)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$FieldAccessExpression.accept(Java.java:3563)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet(UnitCompiler.java:5070)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:2675)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$4500(UnitCompiler.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$7.visitAssignment(UnitCompiler.java:2619)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Assignment.accept(Java.java:3405)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:2654)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:1643)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$1100(UnitCompiler.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$4.visitExpressionStatement(UnitCompiler.java:936)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$ExpressionStatement.accept(Java.java:2097)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:958)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileStatements(UnitCompiler.java:1007)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:2293)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:518)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:658)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:662)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$600(UnitCompiler.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$MemberClassDeclaration.accept(Java.java:1035)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileDeclaredMemberTypes(UnitCompiler.java:769)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:532)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:393)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$400(UnitCompiler.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitPackageMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$PackageMemberClassDeclaration.accept(Java.java:1139)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileUnit(UnitCompiler.java:322)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.compileToClassLoader(SimpleCompiler.java:383)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.compileToClass(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.cook(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:550)
    ... 35 more
```

Which looks like an error caused by automatic code generation. I'm not quite sure what is going on though. Any ideas on how to debug or how to do such a thing in a different way are appreciated. If there is no other suitable solution to do the same thing, then how do I decrease the size of the automatically generated code to be smaller than the constraint? Can I change the constraint?

Thanks,

Comment: It occurs to me that the problem might not be related to the title - is this error caused by the conversion of the data frame to the RDD[Vector] (`val mat = ...`) or in the calculation of `Statistics.corr(mat)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `pivot` at all? It is an expensive and extremely inefficient operation. Just create a matrix from a data you already have.

Firs lets aggregate your data:

```
val cols = Seq("id", "ip")

val aggregated = df.groupBy(cols.map(col(_)): _*).agg(sum($"msgs").alias("msgs"))
```

Index required columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val cols = Seq("id", "ip")

val indexers = cols.map(c => 
  new StringIndexer().setInputCol(c).setOutputCol(s"${c}_idx").fit(aggregated)
)

val indexed = indexers.foldLeft(aggregated)((d, t) => t.transform(d)).select(
  cols.map(c => col(s"${c}_idx").cast("long")) :+ $"msgs".cast("double"): _*
)
```

Create a matrix:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val rows = new CoordinateMatrix(
  indexed.map{case Row(i: Long, j: Long, v: Double) => MatrixEntry(i, j, v)}
).toRowMatrix.rows

Statistics.corr(rows, "pearson")
```

Comment: Thanks. That definitely solves the error I was getting above and is generally a much better way to construct a matrix. Thanks so much for the help.