# Apache Spark Codegen Stage grows beyond 64 KB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, codegen, janino

I'm getting an error when I'm feature engineering on 30+ columns to create about 200+ columns. It is not failing the job, but the ERROR shows. I want to know how can I avoid this.

Spark - 2.3.1 Python - 3.6

Cluster Config - 1 Master - 32 GB RAM, 16 Cores 4 Slaves - 16 GB RAM, 8 Cores

Input data - 8 partitions of parquet file with snappy compression.

My Spark-Submit ->

```
spark-submit --master spark://192.168.60.20:7077 --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 10G --driver-cores 5 --driver-memory 25G --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=60 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=2G --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseParallelGC" --conf spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity=20000 --conf spark.sql.codegen=true /appdata/bblite-codebase/pipeline_data_test_run.py > /appdata/bblite-data/logs/log_10_iter_pipeline_8_partitions_33_col.txt
```

Stack-Trace below -

```
ERROR CodeGenerator:91 - failed to compile: org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException: Compiling "GeneratedClass": Code of method "processNext()V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3426" grows beyond 64 KB
org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException: Compiling "GeneratedClass": Code of method "processNext()V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3426" grows beyond 64 KB
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileUnit(UnitCompiler.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.compileToClassLoader(SimpleCompiler.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.compileToClass(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.cook(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:204)
    at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:1417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1490)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.compile(CodeGenerator.scala:1365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.liftedTree1$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:579)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.inputRDDs(SortExec.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec.doExecute(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doExecute(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec.doExecute(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doExecute(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.buildBuffers(InMemoryRelation.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.<init>(InMemoryRelation.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$cacheQuery$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.writeLock(CacheManager.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.cacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.persist(Dataset.scala:2924)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException: Code of method "processNext()V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3426" grows beyond 64 KB
```

Comment: What kind of operation you are doing?

Comment: `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage", false)` try with this property

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that when Java programs generated using Catalyst from programs using DataFrame and Dataset are compiled into Java bytecode, the size of byte code of one method must not be 64 KB or more, This conflicts with the limitation of the Java class file, which is an exception that occurs.

**Hide error :**

```
spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage= "false"
```

**Workaround :**

In order to avoid occurrence of an exception due to above restriction, within Spark, a solution is to split the methods that compile and make Java bytecode that is likely to be over 64 KB into multiple methods when Catalyst generates Java programs It has been done.

Use persist or any other logical separation in pipeline

Comment: Have the same error and `persist`/`cache` works for me

Comment: Is this configuration available with Spark 2.3.2 version?

Comment: Changing this config will affect performance though since it will disable some underlying optimizations, as explained [here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/6122906529858466/293651311471490/5382278320999420/latest.html)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using pyspark 2.3+, try

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('tow-way')\
        .config('spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage', 'false')\ ## <-- add this line
        .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 3):

As written by vaquar, introducing a logical separation in the pipeline should help.

One way to cut the lineage and introduce a break in the plan seems to be a
`DF -> RDD -> DF` round-trip conversion:

```py
df = spark_session.sparkContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema=df.schema)
```

In book High Performance Spark they further mention it is better (faster) to do this using underlying Java RDDs, i.e. using

`j_rdd = df._jdf.toJavaRDD()` and its schema `j_schema = df._jdf.schema()` to construct a new Java DataFrame and finally convert that back to PySpark DataFrame:

```py
sql_ctx = df.sql_ctx
java_sql_context = sql_ctx._jsqlContext
new_java_df = java_sql_context.createDataFrame(j_rdd, j_schema)
new_df = DataFrame(new_java_df, sql_ctx)
```

Answer (score 3):

We resolved this error by adding extra "checkpoints" in code.

Checkpoints = You need to write the dataframe( data) back to disk in our case s3 and then read it back in a new dataframe which leads to process of empty the JVM spark containers and re launch with new code

Details on checkpoint

https://github.com/JerryLead/SparkInternals/blob/master/markdown/english/6-CacheAndCheckpoint.md

Answer (score 0):

We face a use case that we needed to read ~10K keys from HBase, with prefix filter.

This error occurred because we needed to generate 10K startWith() conditions with OR between them, and the generated code was beyond 64K.

The final solution was to generate groups of keys for each dataframe, and union the results.

This breaks the generation code into smaller pieces