# How to resolve spark processnext() error on spark-submit with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a spark-submit Pyspark job and have been running into this error a lot recently. Does anyone if this can be resolved with the settings?

> ERROR codegen.CodeGenerator: failed to compile:
>   org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException: Compiling
>   "GeneratedClass": Code of method "processNext
>   ()V" of class
>   "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1"
>   grows beyond 64 KB org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException:
>   Compiling "GeneratedClass": Code of method "processNext()V" of class
>   "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Generated
>   Class$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1" grows beyond 64 KB

Comment: does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50891509/2129801) help you?